# Why single quotes change to double quotes in this example?

Tags: postgresql

Look at:

```
foo=> select row('foo bar',42,1.99);   -- or
foo=> select ('foo bar',42,1.99);
         row
---------------------
 ("foo bar",42,1.99)
(1 row)
```

Where do those double quotes come from and what do they mean?

Comment: "" Come from the response of your selection query. Give a look into this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-IO-SYNTAX)

> The composite output routine will put double quotes around field values if they are empty strings or contain parentheses, commas, double quotes, backslashes, or white space. (Doing so for white space is not essential, but aids legibility.) Double quotes and backslashes embedded in field values will be doubled